# Как сделать многоуровневый нумерованный список на html + css, чтобы многоуровневый список отображался в Word?

Tags: html, css, ms-word

Данный пример в браузере отображается, как многоуровневый нумерованный список, а в word как одноуровневый нумерованный список

```html
<HTML>
            <HEAD>
                <STYLE>
     ol {
     /* убираем стандартную нумерацию */
     list-style: none; 
     /* Идентифицируем счетчик и даем ему имя li. Значение счетчика не указано - по умолчанию оно равно 0 */ 
     counter-reset: li; 
     }
     li:before {
     /* Определяем элемент, который будет нумероваться — li. Псевдоэлемент before указывает, что содержимое, вставляемое при помощи свойства content, будет располагаться перед пунктами списка. Здесь же устанавливается значение приращения счетчика (по умолчанию равно 1). */
     counter-increment: li; 
     /* С помощью свойства content выводится номер пункта списка. counters() означает, что генерируемый текст представляет собой значения всех счетчиков с таким именем. Точка в кавычках добавляет разделяющую точку между цифрами, а точка с пробелом добавляется перед содержимым каждого пункта списка */
     content: counters(li,".") ". "; 
     }
    </STYLE>
            </HEAD>
            <BODY>
   <ol>
     <li>пункт</li> <!-1.->
     <li>пункт           
    <ol>
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.1.->
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.2.->
      <li>пункт
     <ol>
       <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.1.->
       <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.2.->
       <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.3.-> 
     </ol>
      </li> <!-2.3.->
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.4.->  
    </ol>
     </li> <!-2.->
     <li>пункт</li> <!-3.->        
     <li>пункт</li> <!-4.->        
   </ol>
   </BODY>
        </HTML>
```

Comment: @Yuri разметка с твоими правками не верна

Comment: Простите, думал, что это не имеет значения. Откатал. Ещё раз тысячи извинений :)

Comment: Что именно неверно? Вроде наоборот, он всё хорошо отредактировал.

Comment: @Qwertiy я попробовал, как Yuri посоветовал. У меня получился маркерованный список.

Comment: @Yiri, спасибо за помощь. В вашем коде были удалены все теги <ol>. Так ведь?

Comment: @Max, нет, не были. Вот ссылка на его версию: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/612482/2. Он просто сделал полноценный сниппет, растащив html и css на два блока, а также выкинул оболочку страницы, т. к. сниппет её добавляет сам. Вообще, список версий можно просмотреть нажав на ссылку "изменён 20 мин. назад" под вопросом. Там можно ещё и откатить вопрос к желаемой версии. И это был не совет, а просто правка вопроса, чтобы улучшить его читаемость.